# Rails - Intermitten undefined method error while hosting on Heroku - works fine locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-postgres

I recently added a `full_name` column to my app.
Everything works fine locally but when I pushed to Heroku, I am experiencing intermittent an `undefined method` error each time I refresh the page but it's only for the `full_name` column I recently added.

```
2015-11-24T08:09:50.910236+00:00 app[web.1]:   Setting Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
2015-11-24T08:09:50.906847+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
2015-11-24T08:09:50.913325+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered users/_form.html.haml (1.5ms)
2015-11-24T08:09:50.913413+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered users/new.html.haml within layouts/application (5.5ms)
2015-11-24T08:09:50.913542+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
2015-11-24T08:09:50.915353+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-11-24T08:09:50.915355+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `full_name' for #<User:0x007f253acdbe30>):
2015-11-24T08:09:50.915356+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: = simple_form_for @user, html: {novalidate: false, class: "form-inline"} do |f|
2015-11-24T08:09:50.915357+00:00 app[web.1]:     2:     = f.input :full_name, label: false, placeholder: "Full Name", input_html: {required: false }
2015-11-24T08:09:50.915358+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:     = f.input :email, as: :email, label: false, placeholder: "Email", input_html: {required: true }
2015-11-24T08:09:50.915358+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:     .form-group.submit
2015-11-24T08:09:50.915359+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:             = f.button :submit, "STEP INSIDE", class: "btn btn-branded"
2015-11-24T08:09:50.915360+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/users/_form.html.haml:2:in `block in _app_views_users__form_html_haml___3156326731190536782_69898937276340'
2015-11-24T08:09:50.915361+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/users/_form.html.haml:1:in `_app_views_users__form_html_haml___3156326731190536782_69898937276340'
2015-11-24T08:09:50.915361+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/users/new.html.haml:10:in `_app_views_users_new_html_haml__101258440498919246_69898938792180'
2015-11-24T08:09:50.915362+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:20:in `new'
```

Could it be that I am on Heroku's free plan?

Comment: Please make sure, your User object doesn't have nil values. 
Its not about free plan, that is for sure.

Answer (score 0):

my dumbass forgot to exe: `heroku restart` - works fine now.
perhaps i should stop coding and go to sleep since it's 3:30 in the morning.